# nodejs using callback and event

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to nodejs programming. so be patient with me.

I have two nodejs modules. One passes passes a message to another nodejs module. the second processes it and pass result back
to the first module.

**method 1**

first module

```
:
secondModule.callFunction(message, function(data){
    //deal with the return message from the second module

})
:
```

second module

```
:
function callfunction(message, callback){

   //asynchornous functions for processing
   callback(data);
} 
:
```

**method 2**

same thing but done using event emitters in the second module

first module

```
:
secondModule.callFunction(message){

})
secondModule.on('done_event', function(data){
    //deal with the reply
});
:
```

second module (uses event emitter)

```
 :

 function callFunction(message){

//asynchornous functions for processing
self.emit('done_event', data);
 } 
 :
```

Are they both correct. what is the difference in these things (both are asynchornous)
or have i done something stupid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Differences between plain callbacks and [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html) events (which is node's implementation of [publisher-subscriber pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern))

- You can attach multiple listeners to same event. Callbacks are one-to-one notifications, events - one-to-many.
- You can't return value from event. Events are one way messages.
- Often, callbacks follow (error, data1, data2, data3, ...) signature because single callback responsible for normal and error data flow (and async libraries usually expect this behaviour)
- EventEmitter-based api, on the other hand tend to separate error and non-error messages
- "error" event is special in event emitter: if there is no listener for it, EventEmitter throws an exception. With callbacks it's your responsibility to check first error parameter.

In your example both approaches are valid.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of events is that events are used when you want to "break" up your processing in pieces, and/or you don't really know when things are happening. So if your `callFunction` was a long running task (e.g. doing or waiting a lot for IO), you could break it into pieces and submitting, for instance, `data` events while it's processing, and then finish with a `done` event. However, if it's merely a "normal" function call, I would simply use a callback.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say events are for plain notifying when an emitter tells everyone interested about some thing happened. It doesn't care what they will do with this fact, it just tells and forgets. Of course you can return a value from an event (by changing fields of an object provided in parameters) but this looks ugly, non-robust and not logical having in mind that event model presumes multiple listeners.

Callbacks OTOH are for requesting a value. You call for user's help with some data and require result.

For example:

**Event** - `server.on('connection')`. Client connected, you tell about it and forget.

**Callback** - `server.isIPAllowedCallback(socket): Boolean`. There's a client, you want to check if this IP is allowed.

Main reason for this difference is bubbling event model with multiple listeners. In languages where you just use one listener like `someObject.onSomeEvent = someEventHandler` there's no difference between handlers and callbacks.